# Xubuntu multibootusb never ending dots

Tags: linux, multi-boot, xubuntu

When trying to boot xubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64 from a multibootusb usb it shows memdisk and then xubuntu and then it appears to load but it's just printing dots (not in the terminal-black screen, but before that).

How can I boot xubuntu properly (live boot) using multibootusb?

EDIT
I pressed ESC which just aborted the current "boot" jumping to boot> where I tried to boot xubuntu again, which still didn't work.
I waited very long which didn't do anything.
I downloaded the iso from a different mirror which changed nothing.

Comment: Press ESC at that point and you may see error messages.

Comment: I pressed ESC at that point and it aborted. I didn't see any error message. Did I miss something or?

Comment: Probably you didn't. I said you *may* see messages but sometimes there's nothing. Try safe graphics mode.

Comment: It should show the initial Grub menu with the "Try Xubuntu" and also "Try Xubuntu (safe graphics)".

Comment: Using multibootusb there is the multibootusb boot menu and from there you can enter the classic grub. Booting xubuntu from multibootusb results in the endless dots. Booting from grub2 results in a short dark screen, followed by being back at grub2. The error happens before getting the option try xubuntu and so on

Answer (score 0):

The current version of xubuntu is not supported by multibootusb even though it says so on https://mbusb.aguslr.com/isos.html. At least that's indicated by the message shown when installing it.
Using memdisk is suggested as a workaround though.